# JPanel class is not adding to JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I can't get my JFrame from main class to display JPanel from another class. Everything compiles without errors
This is my main class code which extends JFrame:

```
public OnlineCarSalesSystem(){
    setTitle("Online Car Sales System");
    setVisible(true);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(new Login());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new OnlineCarSalesSystem();
}
```

In the above code i have added `add(new Login());` but it is not displaying that panel on my JFrame. And in the below code i extended my class with the JPanel. And this is the JPanel class code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login extends JPanel{
    JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login ID");
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JTextField loginTextField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField passwordTextField = new JPasswordField();
    JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton registration = new JButton("new Registration");
    JLabel noaccountLabel = new JLabel("No Account yet!!!");
    public void Login(){
        setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setVisible(true);
        loginLabel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        passwordLabel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        loginTextField.setBounds(680, 103,90,20);
        add(loginTextField);
        loginLabel.setBounds(600, 100,90,30);
        add(loginLabel); 
        passwordTextField.setBounds(680, 153,90,20);
        passwordTextField.setEchoChar('*');
        add(passwordTextField);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(600, 150,90,30);
        add(passwordLabel); 
        add(submitButton);
        submitButton.setBounds(640,200,90,30);
        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   //////Submit Button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        add(registration);
        registration.setBounds(638,270,96,30);
        add(noaccountLabel);
        noaccountLabel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        noaccountLabel.setBounds(640,250,90,30);
        registration.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   //////registration Button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). *"but it is not displaying that panel"* The `null` layout is the likely cause.

Comment: 3) `public void Login(){` If you intend that as a **constructor,** it should be `public Login(){`..

Comment: 4) There is no good reason here, to extend either `JFrame` **or** `JPanel`. Further, given it's a log-in, the frame should instead be a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Login()`-function isn't executed at any point in code. You might want to change

```
public void Login() { ... }
```

to

```
public Login() { ... }
```

so the code gets executed on object initialization